# upload 3 out of 4 coulmns into SQL server from R?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, r, dataframe, rodbc

Consider am having table(myTable) with 4 columns in sql server i.e. `col1`, `col2` ,`col3`, `col4`.

I want to upload or bulkinsert dataframe into "MyTable" using RODBC  library in `R`.

I need to upload this data to `mySql` also using `RMySql` library.

please see my example code below.

```
library(RODBC)

uploaddbconnection=odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=StudentsDB;uid=sa;pwd=sa123;')

outputframe=data.frame(col1=name,col2=age,col3=TotalMarks)

sqlSave(uploaddbconnection, outputframe, tablename ="MyTable",rownames=FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

but the above code returns error.

```
> *Error in sqlSave(uploaddbconnection, outputframe, tablename = TableName,  :    unable to append to table ‘MyTable’*
```

can anyone help me on this.thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that your `outputframe` only has three columns but your SQL table has four columns.  Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: yes. i need to upload these 3 columns only.is any other way to do this.?

Comment: Well what values do you want to insert into the fourth column?

Comment: fourth column should be null.but i dont want to use hardcoding there.becoz column count might change.that's why i put known column values in data frame.

Comment: This is generally not done in SQL.  You should know the columns you are inserting.

Comment: yes i accept.but we can do in sql like insert into MyTable(col1,col2,col3) select col1, col2,col3 from MyTable_2. like this way i want achieve this in R.